# Insert rows autoincrement on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, auto-increment

I have following table

**tbl_Users**

```
Id , UserFile, Name  
1,1200,Jan  
2,1201,Piet  
3,1202,Joris
```

Column one is already an identity column. Now I want to insert a batch from contact persons to  new users.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Users (UserFile,Name)  
    SELECT [AutoIncrement], Name 
    FROM tbl_ContactPerson 
    WHERE (ContactType = 'U')
```

My problem is at `[AutoIncrement]`, how can I add +1 to the `UserFile` column so I have an autoincrement on that column as well?

I am using SQL Server 2008R2

Kind regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the ROW_NUMBER() function in your "batch" select:

```
declare @StartValue int
SELECT @StartValue = MAX(UserFile) FROM tbl_Users 

INSERT INTO tbl_Users (UserFile,Name)   
    SELECT 
        (@StartValue + ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select 1))) as IncrementNumber, 
        Name  
    FROM 
        tbl_ContactPerson  
    WHERE 
        (ContactType = 'U')
```

The (order by (select 1)) is a small hack to number the rows in the order they were returned by the select.

You'll need to seed the @StartValue with an appropriate base number. I've used the previous max of the UserFile value.

**EDIT** Note Andriy M's comment below about atomicity. In the example above, you'd need at least a repeatable-read transaction to ensure consistency.

Comment: +1, but I think you would achieve a higher degree of atomicity by using the `MAX(UserFile)` query directly in the `INSERT ... SELECT` statement (as a subquery).

Comment: The solutions you have given did the job, Thank U

Answer (score 0):

Set the UserFile column to auto_increment too and leave it empty in your select query

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Users (UserFile,Name)  
    SELECT Name FROM tbl_ContactPerson WHERE (ContactType = 'U')
```

or do this

```
INSERT INTO tbl_Users (UserFile,Name)  
    SELECT Max(UserFile) + 1, Name FROM tbl_ContactPerson WHERE (ContactType = 'U')
```

Comment: [Only one identity column can be created per table.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @seed int
SELECT @seed = MAX(UserFile) FROM tbl_Users

CREATE TABLE #temp_users
(
  UserFile identity(@seed + 1, 1)
, Name varchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO #temp_users
  SELECT 
    Name 
  FROM 
    tbl_ContactPerson with (nolock)
  WHERE 
    (ContactType = 'U')

INSERT INTO tbl_Users
(
  UserFile
, Name
)
SELECT
  UserFile
, Name
FROM
  #temp_users

DROP TABLE #temp_users
```